# how to convert data from xml file to excel sheet

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, excel

1: Is there  any way  to covert the  xml data  into  Excel workSheet?

2: Also from database  (sql server  2005  ) to an Excel  worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export data from a Sql Server database to excel.  See this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319951) and this [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx).

As for an xml file, you can easily just open the xml file in Excel.  Depending on the format it should open up for you fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a straight forward one, well documented in Microsoft site http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP010423511033.aspx

If you are talking about doing it programatically, I think the first answer is a good start.